# URL rewriting using localhost is not working

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

I am testing a .htaccess configuration on my localhost.
The root of the website is `http://localhost/test/`

My .htaccess is :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/index2.php
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/index2.php?dest=$1 [L]
```

I can't achieve to redirect any call starting by `http://localhost/test/` to index2.php.
With that .htaccess, and calling `http://localhost/test/index.php`
I have a 404 not found error "The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server.".

I was waiting it to call `http://localhost/test/index2.php?index.php`

TIP : removing the RewriteCond does not change anything

PS : URL Rewriting is enabled and works for simplier examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have not enabled **mod_rewrite** modul.

try to check it in: `AppServ\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

make sure this line without the `#` sign in front

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And this line like this:

```
<Directory "C:/AppServ/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: how you try like this:

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index2.php